# How to write a regular expression that be include "A-Z" and "a-z" and "0-9" and "-" and "_"

Tags: c#, javascript

How to write a regular expression that can be include "A-Z" and "a-z" and "-" and "`_`" character:

- "A-Z" or "a-z" at least one character.
- "0-9" at least zero or more.
- "-" or "_" at least zero or more.

From the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18051288/#comment26411222_18051288):

```
Regex.IsMatch(userName, @"[-a-zA-Z_]+\d*");
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: "Gimme dat regex!" -- Nop.

Comment: Yes.I tried it. but did not work correctly.

Comment: @Jahan Okay, *what* have you tried? Even if it didn't work, showing your attempt at least demonstrates that you tried *something*.

Comment: @Jahan: so show your attempt. And decide what programming language you're using

Comment: I'm using C# and javascript.                       Regex.IsMatch(userName, @"[-a-zA-Z_]+\d*");

Comment: @Jahan Go ahead and edit that into the question. Also, for that snippet, you're only using C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[a-z0-9-_]*[a-z]+[a-z0-9-_]*$` with the `i` flag for case insensitive

Or `^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$`

or

```
-_- [fails, because it's missing a-z or A-Z]
123 [fails, because it's missing a-z or A-Z]
ABC [OK]
A_1 [OK]
_A1 [OK]
1_A [OK]
```